# Where to close mongoDB connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

The following code is a sample of the code I am working with.
As you see in findCollection function I am getting a database service then returning the collection, I am using this function in other places such as Base class, then I will use Base class in other places. my question is where do I close the connection for mongo ?

```
class Collector {
  async findCollection(id) {
    const myservice = await database();
    const mydb = service.getDatabase();
    return mydb.collection('users');
  }
}
module.exports = new Collector();

----------------------------------------------------------------

class Base {
  async makeUser(id) {
    const case = await Collector.findCollection(id);

    return case;
  }
}
module.exports = new Base();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since opening and closing database connections is computationally expensive, you usually try to use a single connection and close it once your app closes entirely.